# Combile multiple CSV Contents into email body with python

Tags: python, email

I have Multiple CSV files like below CSV1 and CSV2 and need to combine both csv into email body using python

```
CSV1 :-
S.No Name Student 
1    Rishabh Engg
2    Samee   Engg

CSV1 :-
S.No Name Student 
1    Ankit   Med
2    Arjun   Engg

=====Expected output i need is like below :-===========

Dear Rishabh ,

PFB the Data :-

CSV1 :-
S.No Name Student 
1    Rishabh Engg
2    Samee   Engg

CSV1 :-
S.No Name Student 
1    Ankit   Med
2    Arjun   Engg
```

Regards,
Rishabh Jaiswal

=========================

FYI , I have tried and sucessfully help to do single csv into email body with below code :-

```
with open('input.csv') as input_file: 
    reader = csv.reader(input_file) 
    data = list(reader) 
    text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid")) 
    html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html")) 
    message = MIMEMultipart( "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')]) 
    message['Subject'] = "Your data" 
    message['From'] = me 
    message['To'] = you 
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server) 
    server.ehlo() 
    server.starttls() 
    server.login(me, password) 
    server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string()) 
    server.quit()
```

Comment: with open('input.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "Your data"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(me, password)
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()

Comment: Please post the code in your question

Comment: @Rakesh: Done and posted

Answer (score 0):

In order to combine the data from both csv files, you need to be reading from both of them. A simple way to do this:

```
import csv
with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as csv1, open('csv2.csv') as csv2:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csv1, delimiter=',')
    reader2 = csv.reader(csv2, delimiter=',')
    all_text = str()
    for row in reader1:
        all_text += ' '.join(row) + '\n'
    for row in reader2:
        all_text += ' '.join(row) + '\n'
    print all_text
```

This will successfully combine the data from the csv files into a singular string. You can play around with the formatting of the all_text string. As for sending the email, it seems as though you can successfully do SMTP through python.

There is also a neat python package called mailmerge that templates emails from csv data https://github.com/awdeorio/mailmerge, I'm not sure if you are templating emails from csv file data, or what your motives are, but maybe this will be useful for you :)

Comment: Thanks @Zachary Spar . But here my goal is combine multiple tables in csv and send them as a mail body.